# empty space is displaying in the site

Tags: html, css

please visit [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) & search for text "Info" using CTRL + F , than you can see as in below image. There is lot of empty space below those texts.

I tried padding, disply :blocks; & some other changes. but nothing worked for me.

```
.dinfo {
    position: relative;
    bottom: 90px;
    right: 50px !important;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Reduce the `line-height` for `li`

Comment: yep as @PrasathV says, line height is at 25px reduce it

Comment: @PrasathV i reduced to 15px; but still empty spaces available & lines are not looking good if i reduce line-height.....

Comment: @SamJones i reduced to 15px; but still empty spaces available & lines are not looking good if i reduce line-height.....

Comment: Do you mean the space between each li or the space between the whole ul and the bottom of the div?

Comment: @SamJones space between the whole ul and the bottom of the div

Comment: I think he means empty space below the last item.

Comment: @Frederik.L you are right

Comment: remove bottom margin from .dinfo class

Comment: something is wrong with the containing div add-to-cart-wrapper you have around it

Comment: @Friend than space will display above the `delivery info` text

Comment: @SamJones please check |& help me for this, i am beginner in css....

Comment: you have position relative and bottom 90px on your .dinfo... quick fix add height 0px to your add-to-cart-wrapper but to solve the problem properly you need to take the position relative and bottom 90px off and sort out your .product-shop div above

Comment: you have a lot of position relative and bottom x pixels inside holding divs, this isnt good practise

Comment: @SamJones agree with you. Position should be absoulte relate to relative..but can't see proper use of position.

Comment: @peter try the answer .. Thought it works...

Comment: @SamJones Thanks a lot, it worked fine, as you said its wrong, but i will try to do some proper css.

Comment: @Leothelion Thanks a lot, it worked fine, as you said its wrong, but i will try to do some proper css.

Comment: @PrasathV Thanks a lot

Comment: @Frederik.L Thanks a lot

Comment: @Friend Thanks a lot

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe yes or else you will face more issue but let us know as we are here to help :)

Comment: @Leothelion  i really need help, its going to take years for me to do proper  position, please tell what code i need to change and what i need to replace

Comment: About this question?? or any other question?

Comment: @Leothelion for this question, as you said the position is not in standard way, please help me for proper positioning of code. as sam jones said `Position is not absoulte relate to relative.`

Comment: yes coz parent should be position:relative and then give position:absolute to child. That's the proper way..but if you want i can dig more to see easy solution for you.

Comment: @Leothelion yes, i need your help ,  please look at the code & help me what code i need to replace by what code.

Comment: do following First remove float:right from .product-view .add-to-cart-wrapper, .product-view .block-related and remove this class too .dinfo and apply this background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/product_view_line.png") no-repeat scroll 0 21px / 428px 2px;  in styles.css line no 8366

Comment: also try to take that div inside the first one so there should be one div in left containing mobile image and second div in right which contain 2 div.

Comment: @Leothelion i will try this , thanks for your support.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't mention the height for this div.... Include this on your css

`.add-to-cart-wrapper
{
max-height: 60px;
}`

Use height or max-height

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. if you check there, you can see horizontal line http://prnt.sc/c4bk35 displaying after those texts, i want to move the line to up , please help me for this.

Comment: next to text "order"

Comment: That was image can't remove that... If you removes means text too cleared..

Comment: is it possible to move that "line" bit upside as [here](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/seamless-pattern-roses-and-freesia-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)

Comment: No possibilities... you have set that as background image on last comment

Comment: please give me code to `set that as background image`

Comment: `.sampleclass{
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) url("../images/product_view_line.png")    no-repeat scroll;
    display: block;
}`

Comment: sorry i added that code, but still that image is displaying

Comment: U have given two links and described ur problem... Kindly send again the particular link and describe the problem... I have confused of becoz two links...

Comment: i want to move the line upside present in this [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/colored-marble-micromax-canvas-knight-a350-phone-case.html) as like this [link](http://sbdev2.kidsdial.com/seamless-pattern-roses-and-freesia-apple-iphone-4-phone-case.html)

Answer (score 2):

Just add custom height to `add-to-cart-wrapper div`. It will work

[image]

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. if you check there, you can see horizontal line http://prnt.sc/c4bk35 displaying after those texts, i want to move the line to up , please help me for this.

Comment: @nsdlfefinedieicbe let me go through that.If my answer helped you can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1):

Height attribute associated with the image is restricting to render this image on the page. Removing height attribute from the image will help.

Comment: Thanks it worked fine. if you check there, you can see horizontal line http://prnt.sc/c4bk35 displaying after those texts, i want to move the line to up , please help me for this.